# I tried to remove Python and think I may have broken my whole operating system (Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

So over the summer I tried switching to Python3 and wanted to get rid of all previous Python versions on my computer. I just went through the files on my computer and threw anything that said Python in the trash. I've been having issues running Python scripts on my computer every since and as I've been digging online for help on uninstalling and reinstalling Python, I've seen many people warn not to delete Apple-supplied system Python. I'm getting the feeling I may have done this....

What can I do if that is the case? Am I completely doomed? Is there a way to check what files should be on my computer and which shouldn't?

This has been really inhibiting me from doing work and I would love to get to the root of this issue. I have run commands in the terminal to install Python3 and force link it but my issues persist and I can't run Python scripts that work perfectly well on my coworkers computers.

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code and when I run my script I get an error that says

```
/bin/sh: python: command not found
```

or when I run my script using the terminal

```
python3 Desktop/folder/file.py
```

it'll say:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've been struggling with this for months, I believe there's something going on with my operating system. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if this adds more context but around the same time I started having this issue, I also started having an issue with my terminal and have had to run this command: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
to get my terminal to recognize any other commands I enter

Comment: MacOS Catalina doesn't _let_ you damage the core OS-vendor-provided code -- the root filesystem is read-only. Which version are you on here?

Comment: Where I'd suggest starting wrt. debugging is [edit]ing the question to include your current `PATH` value, and also the output from `type python` and `type python3`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When I run "type python" in my VSCode terminal it returns "python is /usr/bin/python" or when I use my regular terminal it'll return "python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)". When I run "type python3" on VSCode it returns "python3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3)" but on my other terminal it returns "python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3".

Answer (score 2):

Backup and then re-install the OS.

That's all pretty easy to do with a mac.  But if you've removed things out of the OS folders and you're not sure what, the only real way to get back to normal is to reinstall

Comment: What @Richard said... 
I did a similar thing on an Ubuntu 18 installation on my laptop... It was not pretty...
I ran `uninstall` and a ton of packages were removed.
When I realized what happened, I new I was in HUGE trouble when the install python command only installed ONE package....
I backed up my important files to an external drive, and re-installed the OS.

That will probably be the most time-efficient solution for you, instead of trying to find and install missing software.

Comment: Soo if I re-install the OS that's essentially wiping my computer clean correct? Like as if it were brand new? I just want to make sure I understand the magnitude of this since everywhere I see people talking about this issue seem to say it's big trouble like you mentioned

Comment: Not necessarily - with a Mac you can re-install only the OS, and not wipe the entire machine (ie not delete your user files).  Check out some of the mac help.

Comment: oh - by the way - when you get your mac back, try using Anaconda/Conda to install and manage python installs etc.  IMO it's the easiest way to install and manage python versions/packages etc on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, I can update as more information comes in. I
noticed a couple of issues, so wanted to point them out. First:

```
/bin/sh: python: command not found
```

Depending on the environment, you might not have a `python` even if everything
is correct. You might only have a `python3`. To test, try:

```
python3 -V
```

so if need be, you could edit files to call the correct executable, or perhaps
make a symlink, like one of these:

```
ln -s /bin/python3 /bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Then this:

```
python3 Desktop/folder/file.py
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

You probably should be calling `/Desktop` instead of `Desktop`, depending on the
current directory.